# connecting collectionView to tableView

Tags: swift

I have `CollectionView` on my main storyboard with 5 cells in it, after clicking those cells, `CollectionView` on storyboard moves on another view which is `TableView` and inside of the table view cells I want to put my data which is an array. my code works fine until putting data into `TableView`

any solution will be appericated <3

```swift
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cars.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
        cell?.setup(with: cars[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
    }
}
extension ViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cars.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TableViewController") as? TableViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.configure(with: cars[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

DATA `Cars`:

```swift
struct Cars {
    let carName:String
    let carModel:[String]
}
let cars:[Cars] = [
    Cars(carName: "Mercedes", carModel: ["S Class","A Class", "B Class"]),
    Cars(carName: "BMW", carModel: ["X5","X6","X7"]),
    Cars(carName: "Ford", carModel: ["Fuison","Focus","Mustang"]),
    Cars(carName: "Toyota", carModel: ["Camry", "Corolla"]),
    Cars(carName: "Hyundai", carModel: ["Elantra"])
]
```

table view cell code:

```swift
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
    func configure(with cars:Cars){
        lbl.text = cars.carName
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: please add full code, the code looks fine.

Comment: have you set tableview datasource ?